# JQueryUI Autocomplete - use previous field value as a condition on a different field

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to have two autocompleted fields.  The first one works, as it is the straightforward example of autocomplete.  The second field's autocomplete validation includes the value of the first field as a condition in the query.  I have been chasing this back and forward and I am unsure if it is Jquery or PHP where my issue lies.

HTML and Jquery

```
  <form action='' method='post'>
    <p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' id='country' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
    <p><label>State:</label><input type='text' id='state' name='state' value='' class='auto'></p>
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#country.auto").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1,
        change: function (event, ui){
            if (!ui.item) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#state.auto").autocomplete({
        source: "statesearch.php?country=" + $("#country.auto").val(),
        minLength: 1,
        change: function (event, ui){
            if (!ui.item) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        }
    }); 


});
</script>
```

PHP for second field (first is working fine):

```
$country = $_GET['country'];

if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT state FROM states WHERE state LIKE :term and country ='.$country);
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['state'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

The states table in the DB is simple, three columns, ID, country, state

Thanks in advance for any clues or steps I could go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the function source to do this in the current jqueryui release, per the API guide: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

```
    $(function(){
    $("#state").autocomplete({
        //source: "statesearch.php?country="+country_selection,
        source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "statesearch.php",
          data: {
            country : $("#country").val(),
            term : request.term
          },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data )
          }
        });
    },
        minLength: 1,
        change: function (event, ui){
            if (!ui.item) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
<script>
val country_selected = $("#country").val()
Alert(country_selected);
$(function(){
    $("#state").autocomplete({
        source: "statesearch.php?country=" + country_selected,
        minLength: 1,
        change: function (event, ui){
            if (!ui.item) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        }
    }); 


});
</script>
```

and please tell us if the statesearch.php page is called with the correct url.
Note that if you reference an item by id (#country for example) there is no need to further detail the selection. ID are unique

Comment: I have done some additional testing.  I know the PHP is correct because if I change this to source: "statesearch.php?country="

Comment: I have done some additional testing.  I know the PHP is correct because if I change this to source: "statesearch.php?country=United%20States" it works.   I am starting to think the issue is with when the script is firing to get the value.

Comment: Editing my answer to show if you get the value. What do you see? What is returned by the alert?

Comment: `$(function(){
    $("#state").autocomplete({
        source: "statesearch.php?country=".concat(country_value),
        minLength: 1,
        change: function (event, ui){
            if (!ui.item) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        }
    }); 
});`

Comment: ? Have you applied my solution?

Comment: still getting the hang of the code blocks, apologies.  So in the snippet above, essentially i a trying to concatenate the strings.  If i actually replace the variable country_value with "United%20States" it does work.  It something to do with variables here.  Maybe the base code does not allow for this?

Comment: Trying new solution now.

Comment: Change your code with my solution. What you want to get is easy to get

Comment: Your solution did not work, but it was very helpful to the eventual working solution!  Your idea of the alert showed me that the variable was blank, which was only part of the issue.  I got to digging through the API Guide, and when you use a string as a source, you can't add to it like that.  So while in the API guide, i discovered you need to use the function as a source.  here is my working code snippet: